# JQuery Multiple Selectors AND operator

Tags: jquery

I have 3 elements with different IDs. On click of a submit button, I should validate whether any one of the fields is filled with data. If none of them are filled, suitable message should be shown to the user. If any one of them is filled, the form should be submitted.

Though they belong to the same class, I will not be able to use class selectors as there are other fields with the same class for which this validation does not apply.

I have done the following but does not work

`if( $("#id1,#id2,#id3").val() == "")`  -->> this uses OR operator and I am looking for AND

`if( $("#id1#id2#id3").val() == "")`  --> does not work

`if( $("#id1[#id2][#id3]").val() == "")`  --> neither does this

Comment: The problem is your understanding of [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/), which Gets the current value of the *first element* in the set of matched elements.

Comment: I am looking for a validation on all the fields. Instead of checking each field `$("#id1").val() == ""` && $("#id2").val() == ""`, I felt its better to use multiple selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [jQuery add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/), you're also going to need to loop through all of them to check for each one, so for your example:

```
var valid = true;
$("#id1").add("#id2").add("id3").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "")
        valid = false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to achieve the desired result by modifying a little `var count = new Number(0);
 $("#id1").add("#id2").add("#id3").each(function() {
   if ($(this).val() == "")
  count++;
 });
 if (count == 3)
 {
  alert("Please enter some data.");
  return false;
 }
`

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd use the `each` method

```
var $empty = false;

$("#id1,#id2,#id3").each(function(i, e){
    if ($(e).val() == '') $empty = true;
});

if ($empty)
{
    alert("Please enter some data.");
}
```

Comment: Just thought I'd add that I'm a PHP guy which is why my variables in JS start with a $ which I believe is frowned upon but whatever :) you don't have to use it.